# mouseover, mouseout only works on largest shape

Tags: kineticjs, mouseover

Hi im using Kinetic to draw some  bubbles from data sent via json.
My code seems to work and generates the bubbles fine.
Im trying to get an effect on mouser over to start with, and then the next stag will be to produce a tool-tip for each bubble,
But currently the mouse over will only work on the largest bubble?
Can any one see anything wrong with my code

I have added a picture so you can see what is [image: being generated]

```
<script >
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container: 'graph',
      width: 1000,
      height: 1000
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    // setup graph padding
    var graph;
    var xPadding = 30;
    var yPadding = 30;

    var drawGraph = new Kinetic.Shape ({
      sceneFunc: function(ctx){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(xPadding, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(xPadding, stage.height() - yPadding);
        ctx.lineTo(stage.width(), stage.height() - yPadding);
        //Draw the X value texts
        // for(var i = 0; i < projects.values.length; i ++) {
        //     ctx.fillText(data.values[i].X, getXPixel(i), graph.height() - yPadding + 20);
        //  }

        // Draw the Y value texts
         ctx.textAlign = "right"
         ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
         ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
         for(var i = 0; i < getMaxY(); i += 5) {
            ctx.fillText((i), xPadding - 15, getYPixel(i));
        }
        ctx.fillStrokeShape(this);
      },
      stroke: 'black',
      strokeWidth: 1
    });![enter image description here][2]     

    $.getJSON( "bubble_data.json", function( data ) {
        var maxHour= data.max_hour_task; 
        $.each( data.projects, function(i) {
            //calculate the number of days between two dates
            var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
            var startOfQ = new Date(2014,00,00);
            var startDate = new Date(data.projects[i].summary.created_on);
            var endDate = new Date(data.projects[i].summary.target_date);
            var startDayPos = (Math.round(Math.abs((startOfQ.getTime() - startDate.getTime())/(oneDay))))*6;
            var diffDays = (Math.round(Math.abs((startDate.getTime() - endDate.getTime())/(oneDay))))*6;
            var endDayPos = startDayPos + diffDays ;
            hours=(data.projects[i].summary.total_hours);
            base = stage.height() - yPadding;
            getMaxY(hours);
            hours_scale =((stage.height()-(stage.height() - (((stage.height() - yPadding) / maxHour)))) *hours)
            total_hours = 970 - hours_scale;
            var bubble = new Kinetic.Shape({
              sceneFunc: function(ctx) {
              var x=this.myX;
              var y=this.myY;
              var w=this.myW;
              var h=this.myH;
              var kappa = .5522848,
              ox = (w / 2) * kappa, // control point offset horizontal
              oy = (h / 2) * kappa, // control point offset vertical
              xe = x + w,           // x-end
              ye = y + h,           // y-end
              xm = x + w / 2,       // x-middle
              ym = y + h / 2;       // y-middle
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(x, ym);
              ctx.bezierCurveTo(x, ym - oy, xm - ox, y, xm, y);
              ctx.bezierCurveTo(xm + ox, y, xe, ym - oy, xe, ym);
              ctx.bezierCurveTo(xe, ym + oy, xm + ox, ye, xm, ye);
              ctx.bezierCurveTo(xm - ox, ye, x, ym + oy, x, ym);
              ctx.closePath();
              ctx.fillStrokeShape(this);

              },
              fill: 'rgba(142, 214, 255, 0.1)',
              stroke: 'black',
              strokeWidth: 1
            });
            bubble.myX=startDayPos;
            bubble.myY=base;
            bubble.myW=endDayPos;
            bubble.myH=-hours_scale;

            bubble.on('mouseover', function() {
              console.log(this);
              this.fill('blue');
              bubble.draw();
            });

            bubble.on('mouseout', function() {
              console.log(this);
              this.fill('rgba(142, 214, 255, 0.1)');
              bubble.draw();
            });
            layer.add(bubble);
        });
        layer.add(drawGraph);
        stage.add(layer);
    }); 


    function getMaxY() {
        var max = 0;
            if(hours > max) {
            max = hours;
            }
        max += 10 - max % 10;
        return max;

    }

    // // function getXPixel(val) {
    // //     return ((graph.width() - xPadding) / projects.values.length) * val + (xPadding * 1.5);
    // // }

    function getYPixel(val) {
        return stage.height() - (((stage.height() - yPadding) / getMaxY()) * val) - yPadding;

    }


    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that Kinetic maintains a z-index for each shape -- even for semi-transparent shapes.

So your mouseover & mouseout events will fire for only the **topmost** shape under the mouse (not for all shapes under the mouse)

If you want to trigger tooltips for all shapes under the mouse you can use `stage.getAllIntersections`

Note:  `.getAllIntersections` is a computationally expensive operation so you will take a performance hit when using it.

Comment: Thank you for this.
Can i set z-index for each shape?
for example if i work out the area and give the shapes with the smallest area the highest z index

Comment: The z-indexes default to last-added-higher-z-index.  And yes, you can reorder later using myShape.moveToTop() and myShape.moveToBottom().